# How to override toString() inside wrapper class?

Tags: java, overriding, wrapper, tostring

I was shown a way to parse some data from a database to an entity. I was given this good wrapper class

```
public class ObjectWrapper implements Wrapper{
   private Object wrappedObject;
//...
public static Wrapper wrap(ResultSet rs, int column, int columnType) throws SQLException {        
        if (columnType == 0) {
            return new EmptyListExceptionWrapper();
        } else {
            return new ObjectWrapper(rs.getObject(column));
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it in order to parse those objects, I get the names like `databaseConnection.ObjectWrapper@5010be6` and not as they really are. Another good fellow told me that I have to override `toString()` method inside `ObjectWrapper` class in order to get the real results.

How am I supposed to do that? I know that those primitive types cannot be added or changed. For example, should I do something like that below?

```
 public static String toString(){
     String str = new String();
     return str += wrappedObject;
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by REAL result?

Comment: I mean the real names. For example, instead of `databaseConnection.ObjectWrapper@5010be6`, `ΔΕ01.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, methods that apply to a specific instance of your class shouldn't be `static`, and you should generally avoid string concatenation in favor of a `StringBuilder`.

Second, a number of tools will create useful `toString` methods for you: your IDE can generate one, and Apache Commons Lang has `ToStringBuilder`.

If you don't have any information about the wrapped type (and its own `toString` implementation), then you might just use something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // uses a StringBuilder implicitly
    return "ObjectWrapper[" + wrappedObject.toString() + "]";
}
```

Comment: Note, you can (and should) just use `wrappedObject` instead of `wrappedObject.toString()`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it works now! And I understood what was going on. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I went ahead and made it explicit as the OP is new to the topic, and the coerced call will be identical anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Object.toString() which is what your are calling in

```
str += wrappedObject;
```

will by default return the object's hashcode.
You need to cast the wrappedObject to something that you can then print properties of

```
class objectDef{
    private int x;
    public int y;
    public int getX() { return x; }
}

//ToString method
public String toString()
{
    return "ObjectWrapper has Y: " + ((objectDef)wrappedObject).y) + " x: " + ((objectDef)wrappedObject).getX() ".";
}
```

Comment: The default `toString` does not use the object's memory address (which is moveable, by the way, and thus inaccessible to Java code); it uses the object's hash code.